# I am trying to display SQL result on a list control using MFC

Tags: sql, visual-c++, mfc, dialog, listcontrol

Please, I have list control on, I want to display my query result on a list control. The program runs without error, but it does not display the SQL result on the list control.

```
BOOL CClassDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // TODO:  Add extra initialization here
    CString DSN;
    DSN = _T("DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=DESKTOP-
DICUCDS\\SQL2K14;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft\x00ae Visual Studio\x00ae 2013;WSID=DESKTOP-
DICUCDS;DATABASE=School");

    CDatabase aDB; 
    try {
        aDB.OpenEx(DSN);  

        CRecordset aRS(&aDB); 
        aRS.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, (L"SELECT DISTINCT Myclass FROM MyFacts"));  

        // populate Grids
        ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(m_classlist, LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);

        // Column width and heading
        m_classlist.InsertColumn(1, L"Class", LVCFMT_LEFT, -1, 1);

        m_classlist.InsertColumn(2, L"Age", LVCFMT_LEFT, -1, 1);
        m_classlist.SetColumnWidth(0, 120);
        m_classlist.SetColumnWidth(1, 200);
        m_classlist.SetColumnWidth(2, 200);

        while(!aRS.IsEOF())   
        {
            CString strValue;
            aRS.GetFieldValue(L"Myclass",  strValue);
            m_classlist.SetItemText(-1, 1, strValue);
            //strValue.AddString(strValue);

            aRS.MoveNext();
        }
        aRS.Close();
        aDB.Close();
    }
    catch (CDBException * ex)
    {
        TCHAR buf[255];

        ex->GetErrorMessage(buf, 255);

        CString strPrompt(buf);
        AfxMessageBox(strPrompt);
    }

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}

void CClassDialog::ResetListControl()
{
    m_classlist.DeleteAllItems();
    int iNbrOfColumns;

    CHeaderCtrl* pHeader = (CHeaderCtrl*)m_classlist.GetDlgItem(0);

    if (pHeader) {
        iNbrOfColumns = pHeader->GetItemCount();
    }

    for (int i = iNbrOfColumns; i >= 0; i--) {
        m_classlist.DeleteColumn(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code first. For example, can you guarentee that it is actually opening the database? Have you actually confirmed it is returning a record set? Have you tried simply adding results into a simpler control like a list box? At the moment you have just shown us a OnInitDialog method and we don't know where the issue is without your providing some context and debug results. Hope teh above helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is right? `m_classlist.SetItemText(-1, 1, strValue);`

If you research the official documentation for the `CListCtrl` (for example, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=msvc-160#insertitem)) you will see:

```
CString strText;

int nColumnCount = m_myListCtrl.GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItemCount();

// Insert 10 items in the list view control.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    strText.Format(TEXT("item %d"), i);

    // Insert the item, select every other item.
    m_myListCtrl.InsertItem(LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_STATE, i, strText,
        (i % 2) == 0 ? LVIS_SELECTED : 0, LVIS_SELECTED, 0, 0);

    // Initialize the text of the subitems.
    for (int j = 1; j < nColumnCount; j++)
    {
        strText.Format(TEXT("sub-item %d %d"), i, j);
        m_myListCtrl.SetItemText(i, j, strText);
    }
}
```

You are making references to `SetItemText` but you have not actually added any elements into the list. The code before shows an example:

```
// Insert the item, select every other item.
m_myListCtrl.InsertItem(LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_STATE, i, strText,
    (i % 2) == 0 ? LVIS_SELECTED : 0, LVIS_SELECTED, 0, 0);
```

I am not saying that you have to use that specific set of paramaters. But the point is that you must insert an item into the list before you can update it's properties. Or even set the properties at the moment you add it into the list.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew. It worked. May I ask you, if I want to use alternative method, like  m_mylistctrl.Addstring, and  m_mylistctrl.Insertstring. Where would they fit in?

Comment: @aloemconsultaloemconsult It is probably best to do new questions for other issues. Also, don't forget to upvote / accept answer when you are happy with it.

Comment: I don’t see those methods listed for CListCtrl: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=msvc-160#insertitem